# Vlookup based upon cell input to warn user depending on vlookup results

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am attempting to have VBA check whenever a new employee ID is entered into the sheet (automatically looks up their information from a database) that if the ID that is entered returns an individual that is considered an associate, a message box will generate informing the user that they are about to select an associate. Currently I am getting a run-time error 424 at the If Application line. I am very new to VBA so if I am making a silly mistake I'm sorry. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edited Code** - Thanks to Doug and Simoco for the help.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim WatchRange As Range
Dim IntersectRange As Range
Set WatchRange = Range("A2:A550")
Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, WatchRange)
If IntersectRange Is Nothing Then
    'Do Nothing Spectacular
Else

On Error Resume Next
 If WorksheetFunction.VLookup(IntersectRange, Me.Range("A2:M550"), 14, False) = "Associate" Then

 MsgBox "You have choosen an associate for this trip!"
 Else


End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `Sheet`, do you mean `Me`, which returns the sheet with the code in it?

Comment: Possibly, I will go try that now. I literally started trying to code last week so I am still trying to understand the basics. Our teacher told us to "find others code and use it". Not the most helpful advice haha.

Comment: I will update my code but I am now getting an error saying "Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction Class". I googled this and found some items about on Error resume next but I don't seem to be able to get that to work. I continue to get the error.

Comment: change `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` to `Application.VLookup` or `WorksheetFunction.VLookup`

Comment: I'm now having the issue that the msgbox is popping up no matter what type of employee is entered in the cells.

Comment: You are specifying 14 columns for a range that's only 13 wide. Either change to 13, or make the range go to N, depending on your setup.

Comment: @simoco, why will that change help?

Comment: @DougGlancy, don't know, but when I ran Op's code, I had the same error, and after changing `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` to `Application.VLookup` it works. The strange thing - after this change  I used `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` again and it works now:)

Comment: That was highly embarrassing...An accounting student should be able to count. Everything works great unless an input cell is cleared and it results in the msgbox. Do I need to enter an entire new set of code that if clear contents is run nothing happens?

Comment: @DougGlancy, `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` didn't work because `You are specifying 14 columns for a range that's only 13 wide`. For some reason `Application.VLookup` ignores this error

Comment: @simoco, `Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` and `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` are the same. `Application.Vlookup` responds to errors differently, and you use `IsErr` to trap. There's good info part way down this [Chip Pearson page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/callingworksheetfunctionsinvba.aspx) or just search on  "application.vlookup versus worksheetfunction.vlookup."

Comment: @DougGlancy, thanks for interesing link, don't know about this:)

Comment: @simoco, given the amazoimg speed and accuracy with which you answer questions, I thought you knew everything about VBA :). Glad I could add to your knowledge.

Comment: @DougGlancy, in VBA there are many subtle details that are hidden behind the scenes and as long as you do not run into the problem that they can cause, you don't know about them, as in that case:)

Comment: Do either of you know how to fix the issue when the cells are deleted or cleared? I have been trying a couple different ways with additional If's but I have been very unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim res As Variant
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A550")) Is Nothing Then
        res = Application.CountIfs(Range("A2:A550"), Target, _
                Range("M2:M550"), "Associate")
        If Not IsError(res) Then
            If res > 0 Then MsgBox "You have choosen an associate for this trip!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Was this code to replace everything else I already have? When I do that it doesn't pop up the MsgBox at all. I have tried integrating it into my previous code and when I do that it just causes the MsgBox to pop up twice. I'm sorry for all the trouble for something probably quite simple.

Comment: You need to check that the `VLOOKUP` returns "Associate" right?

Comment: Correct @DougGlancy, when I ran the code provided by simoco it returned nothing at all. I see that he just edited his code though! Let me try that. I really appreciate all the help guys.

Comment: @Chardo, see my updated answer, there was one thing with your approach. Basically you can't use `VLOOKUP` because `VLOOKUP` finds only first match. E.g. you can have in your worksheet in column A two values with `1`, and only second value has corresponding value in column M equal to "Associate", while first not.

Comment: One last question (wish I could give you guys some cookies), the edited code works great unless the user Clears Content. Is there a way to include this / I am planning to lock all of the vlookup cells on the page anyways so would there be a way to prevent Clear Contents from being activiated?

Comment: @simoco - This works except it pops up an excel message of false every time you do anything (i.e. enter a value, delete a value, clear a value). Is that due to the line:

                MsgBox IsError(res)? I'm doing my best to understand the code as you provide help so hopefully I can help others if they have the same question.

Comment: yup:) it was my "watch":) just delete it. Updated code